# Getting correct scope in functions (not using that = this)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to fix a function I have here to be able to use it without using a that = this (or self = this as some like to use). It is a scoping issue but I am not sure how to get around it, and I would like to get in the habit of not using a that = this .  So the functions are all in a return (angular factory) and I am having trouble referencing another function . Let me show you what I mean :

```
  return {
            loadStates: function() {

                     var that = this;
                     //chgeck if is loaded module, then change and fire callback
                     var currentModules = moduleHolder.getModules();
                     if (currentModules[name]) {
                        //works here
                         this.prepState();

                     } else {
                         //module cannot be found check for 5 seconds
                         $log.warn("Requesting " + name + "...");
                         var timeToCheck = true;
                         setTimeout(function() {
                             timeToCheck = false;
                         }, 5000);
                         var check = {
                             init: function() {
                                 check.checkAgain();
                             },
                             checkAgain: function() {
                                 if (timeToCheck) {
                                     if (currentModules[name]) {
                                        //but not here
                                         that.prepState();
                                     } else {
                                         //still doesn't exists
                                         setTimeout(check.checkAgain, 200);
                                     }
                                 } else {
                                     //doesn't exist after 5 seconds
                                     $log.error("Requested module (" + name + ") could not be found at this time.");
                                 }
                             }
                         };
                         check.init();
                     }

                 },
                 prepState: function() {

                 }

             }
```

So in the top if it finds the currentModule[name] I can use a this.prepState() and it works fine. However inside the timing functions I cannot use the this anything because it is inside a different scope so I have temporarily gotten around this by setting a that = this up top, however I would like see if I could not use this method. How does one get around this without using the that= this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is a scoping issue...

No, it isn't. `this` and scope have essentially nothing to do with each other. (For now; ES6's arrow functions will change that.) It's an issue of *how the functions are called*.

If you pass a function reference to something that will call it later, unless the thing you're passing it to has a way you can use to tell it what to use for `this` when calling it, your function will get called with `this` not referring to what you want it to refer to.

You can get a new function reference that will call your original function with the correct `this` by using `Function#bind`:

```
var usesCorrectThis = originalFunction.bind(valueForThis);
```

So for example, suppose I have:

```
var check = {
    name: "Fred",
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log("Hi, I'm " + this.name);
    }
};
```

If I do:

```
check.sayHello();
```

All is good: Calling the function as part of an expression retrieving it from a property tells the JavaScript engine to use the object as `this` during the call.

However, if I do:

```
setTimeout(check.sayHello, 0);
```

...that doesn't work right, because when `setTimeout` calls the function, it doesn't use the right value for `this`.

So I can use `Function#bind` to address that:

```
setTimeout(check.sayHello.bind(check), 0);
```

More *(on my blog)*:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: I am having trouble applying this to my example. I get what you are saying here but how would I call the equivalent of check.hello.bind(check) on the this?

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways you can do that.
One way is to use bind function.you can use

```
 var checkInitBindFn = check.init.bind(this);
 checkInitBindFn();
```

Secondly you can use call and apply also.

```
check.init.call(this);
check.init.apply(this);
```

Like this you can use this instead of that. 
Check the complete api doc online...

Answer (score 0):

It's not a scoping issue. If you want to avoid `self = this` you can always reference functions by objects. Makes cleaner code and since factories in angular are singletons you're not wasting memory.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', function ($timeout) {

  var myFactory = {
    loadState: function () {

      $timeout(function () {
        myFactory.check();
      }, 500);

    },
    check: function () {

    },
  };

  return myFactory;

});
```